# Why does the same MySql query behaves differently in code and workbench?

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-workbench

Here is a simple mysql query run from my application:

```
    try
    {
         using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
         {
             var storedProcedure = "ReserveConstructB";
             using (var command = new MySqlCommand(storedProcedure, connection))
             {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    connection.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
             }
         }
    }
```

and here is simple stored procedure:

```
BEGIN
    start transaction;
    select *from Kimmel_constructs for update;
END
```

As you can see I do not COMMIT at the end of the procedure, but regardless, when I run this procedure next time it gets executed even though "Kimmel_constructs" is not released and I should get lock_wait_timeout exception. If I call the same procedure in MySql Workbench from different connections, I get the exception which would be the desired behavior. What could be the reason for such a behavior?

Comment: Your `connection` gets closed when disposed ending the transaction hence releasing the locks.

Comment: @sticky bit, Yes, that seems reasonable, but I think this is not the case, because even if procedure is completed and connection gets closed, I still can't call this procedure from workbench -I can only call it from my application.

Answer (score -1):

Because your application probably makes busy mysql. So you need to close connection when your progress done like connection.Close() and I suggest to use:

```
if (con.State==ConnectionState.Open)
{
  con.Close();
}
  con.Open();
```